# Incomplete type while accessing templated derived class (CRTP)' static function while doing SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, crtp

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/75MTtCJR83UxwDdq)

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    void mem_func() {
        // This works!!! Can access static_func<int>();
        std::cout << T::template static_func<int>() << '\n';
    }
    template <typename K>
    static constexpr bool static_func() { return true; }

    template <typename T1>
    typename std::enable_if<T::template static_func<T1>(), void> sfinae_func() { 
        // This breaks!!! T is an incomplete type??
        std::cout << "This fails" <<'\n';
    }
};

struct B : A<B> {
};
```

Here, I don't get why T::static_func is working in the member function foo() but when I go to instantiate  the sfinae_func the same T::static_func is inaccessible as T is incomplete! How can this be??

Follow Up is this:
If the standards restricts me to access T::static_func in enable_if, is there a workaround to hide A::static_funct with T::static_func when required?

```
template <typename T1>
    typename std::enable_if<T::template static_func<T1>(), void> sfinae_func()
```

Here what would need to be done to have enable if call T's static_func such that T's static_func hides A's static_func?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To workaround the problem you could delay type instantiation by making `T` of `sfinae_func` additional template parameter's default value e.g. as follows (oh and don't forget to use inner type of `std::enable_if` to actually perform sfinae):

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
struct A {
    void mem_func() {
        std::cout << T::template static_func<int>() << '\n';
    }
    template <typename K>
    static constexpr bool static_func() { return true; }

    template <typename T1, typename TT = T>
    typename std::enable_if<TT::template static_func<T1>(), void>::type sfinae_func() {
        std::cout << "This fails" <<'\n';
    }
};

struct B : A<B> {
};
int main() {
    B a;
    a.mem_func();
    a.sfinae_func<int>();
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XPGrLj5E7stajnYM)

Comment: In general accessing the method of dependent type's memebers should be accessed on instantiation. The problem is that `T` is not dependent type of `sfinae_func` method and as such it might be perceived by the compiler as it should be accessed immediately on creation and at the time B did not inherit from A yet - is incomplete (as compiler actually suggests)...

Comment: @them bodies are not instantiated until used; signatures are even if not used.